# Counting points in polygon by time / attribute condition

Tags: r, intersection, sf, time-series, count

I have two tables in different databases I cannot connect directly. Table A contains polygons of regions. Table B contains points with timestamps.

I want to count the points in each polygon for a given timerange. In SQL I would do something like this (simplified reproducible example):

```sql
WITH mypolygons(polyid, polygeom) as (
   values(
       'a',
       ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((
                       6.16527585 46.2437628, 
                       6.16527585 49.62165865, 
                       10.42030488 49.62165865, 
                       10.42030488 46.2437628, 
                       6.16527585 46.2437628
                      ))'
                      ),4326)::geometry
   )
),
mypoints(pointtime,pointgeom) as (
    values(
        '2022-01-01 14:12:00'::timestamp,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('Point (7.452982 48.39927093)'),4326)::geometry
    )
),
timepolygons as (
    select
    calendar.*,
    mypolygons.*
    from (select 
          generate_series('2022-01-01 14:00:00'::timestamp,'2022-01-01 14:15:00'::timestamp,'5 minute'::interval) as tstamp_start,
          generate_series('2022-01-01 14:05:00'::timestamp,'2022-01-01 14:20:00'::timestamp,'5 minute'::interval) as tstamp_end
     ) as calendar
    cross join 
    mypolygons
)

select 
timepolygons.*,
coalesce(count(mypoints.*),0) as pnt_cnt
from 
timepolygons
left join
mypoints
on 
ST_Intersects(mypoints.pointgeom,timepolygons.polygeom)
and 
mypoints.pointtime between timepolygons.tstamp_start and timepolygons.tstamp_end
group by
timepolygons.tstamp_start,
timepolygons.tstamp_end,
timepolygons.polyid,
timepolygons.polygeom
```

However, I cannot use SQL in that case. So I thought of using R with sf package. I already wrote my script which creates the `table_polygon`, `table_points` and `table_timepolygon` as sf dataframes similar to the reproducible example above in SQL.

I know I can count the points in polygons using

```
(table_polygon$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(table_polygon, table_points)))
```

but how could I add the time-, or more generally spoken, attribute-condition?

The internet is full of questions asking about "count points in polygon", but I could find no examples using an extra attribute or time condition.

As a workaround I thought of using a loop to iterate over each timespan, getting the points falling within and doing the join. But I guess there has to be another, easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go the R way I would suggest this workflow:

- assign each polygon an unique id / such as the polyid in your example
- perform `sf::st_join(points, polygons)` on your points and polygons objects, with - crucially - your points in the first place of the join; it will produce your points object, enriched by the data columns from the polygons object (such as the unique id / polyid).
- at this step you can drop the geometry (= `sf::st_drop_geometry()`), and do simple aggregation over your time dimension and polygon id, as both are present in your points object; `{dplyr}` is your friend here as you are dealing with a regular data frame object

Since an example is worth 1000 of words :) consider this piece of code. It builds on the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile that ships with `{sf}`.

It first produces five polygons of dissolved North Carolinas stacked on top of each other, with polygon id's from 1 to 5.

Then it produces three semi-random points, two with time character 1 and one with 3 (or whatever).

The third step is where the action happens: first the points are spatially joined to polygons (it will be a kind of a cross join, since all points are in NC) and then the result is filtered on the secondary criterion - I am using polygon id = time, which makes no sense but is there only for the sake of example. Then it is a question of group by and summarise / functionally equivalent to select polygon id, count(*) from yer data group by polygon id in SQL speak.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# a set of polygons in time
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%  # included with sf package
  summarise() %>% # single polygon over entire NC
  tidyr::expand_grid(poly_id = 1:5) %>% # sequence of ids from 1 to 5
  st_as_sf(crs = 4267) # this information was lost during the expand_grid (tidyr equivalent of cross join)

# a set of points in time
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                  x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                  y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333),
                  time = c(1, 1, 3)) %>%  # time, to be matched with poly_id
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>% # CRS of the coordinates
  st_transform(st_crs(shape)) # transorm to CRS of the shape object

# this is the action!   
cities %>% 
  st_join(shape) %>% # spatial join only, without the second criterion (yet)
  st_drop_geometry() %>% # drop geometry (no longer necessary)
  filter(time == poly_id) %>%  # filter over the second condition
  group_by(poly_id) %>%  # group by
  tally(name = "point_totals") # summarise the result
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#  poly_id time_totals
#    <int>       <int>
#1       1           2
#2       3           1
```